# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. - Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed

Tags: help

For some reason I can't get to use Tor... 
First, I got an error that one error and, after trying something that I saw in another question (using bridges), I got another (?) I dont know if its the same...
Can someone help? I'm at a company desktop

First error:

> Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
>
> Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (connection
>   timeout - 109.105.109.162:60784).
>
> Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
>
> Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done -
>   194.109.206.212:443).
>
> 22/05/2017 10:48:25.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not
>   make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all
>   existing connections.  22/05/2017 10:48:25.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork
>   is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections.
>   Shutting down all existing connections.  22/05/2017 10:48:25.000
>   [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept
>   non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing
>   connections.  22/05/2017 10:48:25.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener
>   on 127.0.0.1:9150  22/05/2017 10:48:25.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%:
>   Connecting to directory server  22/05/2017 10:48:26.400 [NOTICE]
>   Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
>   22/05/2017 10:54:17.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%:
>   Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out
>   [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host
>   32EE911D968BE3E016ECA572BB1ED0A9EE43FC2F at 109.105.109.162:60784) 
>   22/05/2017 10:54:17.400 [WARN] 9 connections have failed:  22/05/2017
>   10:54:17.400 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS)
>   with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE  22/05/2017
>   10:54:17.400 [WARN]  4 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL
>   state (No SSL object)  22/05/2017 10:55:22.400 [NOTICE] Closing
>   no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  22/05/2017
>   10:55:22.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or
>   accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing
>   connections.  22/05/2017 10:55:22.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks
>   listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  22/05/2017 10:55:22.400 [WARN] Problem
>   bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory
>   server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host
>   7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at 194.109.206.212:443) 
>   22/05/2017 10:55:22.400 [WARN] 11 connections have failed:  22/05/2017
>   10:55:22.400 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS)
>   with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE  22/05/2017
>   10:55:22.400 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL
>   state (No SSL object)  22/05/2017 10:55:32.000 [WARN] Problem
>   bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory
>   server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host
>   92CFD9565B24646CAC2D172D3DB503D69E777B8A at 178.16.208.57:443) 
>   22/05/2017 10:55:32.000 [WARN] 12 connections have failed:  22/05/2017
>   10:55:32.000 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS)
>   with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE  22/05/2017
>   10:55:32.000 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL
>   state (No SSL object)  22/05/2017 10:55:32.000 [NOTICE] Delaying
>   directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Second error:

> Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
>
> Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done -
>   123.218.105.112:443).
>   22/05/2017 11:10:35.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not
>   make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all
>   existing connections.  22/05/2017 11:10:35.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork
>   is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections.
>   Shutting down all existing connections.  22/05/2017 11:10:35.200
>   [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept
>   non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing
>   connections.  22/05/2017 11:10:35.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener
>   on 127.0.0.1:9150  22/05/2017 11:10:35.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%:
>   Connecting to directory server  22/05/2017 11:10:35.400 [NOTICE]
>   Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
>   22/05/2017 11:11:50.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%:
>   Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 3;
>   recommendation warn; host 0E099DC76934B1A12FA55F847711241B4C26E18E at
>   123.218.105.112:443)  22/05/2017 11:11:50.600 [WARN] 3 connections have failed:  22/05/2017 11:11:50.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in
>   state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)  22/05/2017
>   11:11:50.600 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS)
>   with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE  22/05/2017
>   11:12:09.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on
>   127.0.0.1:9150  22/05/2017 11:12:09.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections.
>   Shutting down all existing connections.  22/05/2017 11:12:09.500
>   [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: What kind of bridges were you using? It looks like they're censoring TLS connections, if you aren't already you should try using a pluggable transport like `obfs4`.

Comment: I'm a noob at this... How do I determine the kind of bridge I used? And how do I use the obfs4?

Comment: Look for a file named `torrc` and see whether it has any lines starting with `Bridge`.

Comment: There are 3 lines: Bridge 162.243.97.18:8443 D211D6C27FED476D4DEA0D0F6A9C7723F35174F1
Bridge 67.205.153.5:8443 E78E40BAFC2749D03281A0F1052E7575C8348FB9
Bridge 123.218.105.112:443 0E099DC76934B1A12FA55F847711241B4C26E18E

Comment: it's a censorship issue, use a bridge or meek similar question:
https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/cant-connect-tor-network-failed-to-establish-network

Comment: Tor failed to establish a tor network connection. Loading network status failed (done-37.157.255.35:9090)