# Tor (with bridges) keeps giving "connections have failed" in command line (while working ok through Tor Browser)?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, bridge, pluggable-transports, connection

When I try to connect to Tor through command line (Windows 10):

`"C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe" -f "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc" | more`

 I get the following error:

```
Mar 11 14:10:01.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Mar 11 14:10:02.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 80%: Connecting to the Tor network. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 1; recommendation warn; host A1A1234A123AB12345A1234A1A1234A123456789 at 0.0.2.0:2)
Mar 11 14:10:03.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 80%: Connecting to the Tor network. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 2; recommendation warn; host A1A1234A123AB12345A1234A1A1234A123456789 at 0.0.2.0:2)
Mar 11 14:10:03.000 [warn] 1 connections have failed:
Mar 11 14:10:03.000 [warn]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Tor **works normally when** I use the Tor Browser (not the command line) with no problem using the same Bridge provided within the *torcc* configuration file.

I'm sure that bridges are working (not blocked) because when I run Tor Browser, connection is established with no problems. I believe something is missing in order to make the command line work successfuly.

**Notes:**
▪ Only it gives me errors when I use Tor over the command line, while it's working succesfully with no problems on the Tor Browser.
▪ I have tried switching bridges (All of them work normally when I use the Tor Browser, but don't work while using command line). So, switching Bridges isn't a solution, there is something missing with the command line usage.

**Further Notes:**
I am aware of other questions, asking about the similar error message, that this one may be marked as a duplicate of:
• [Can't connect Tor Network, failed to establish network](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/cant-connect-tor-network-failed-to-establish-network)

My question is different as it's about not being able to use Tor through command-line with bridges I'm sure they are not blocked (because they are working on Tor Browser within the same computer).

I am looking for using Tor (with Bridge) over the command line (without the need to start Tor Browser) and make connection established successfully through command line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to missing Pluggable-Transports configuration.

The Pluggable-Transports configuration exists within the `torrc-defaults` file.
You can include it using `--defaults-torrc` like this:

```
"C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe" --defaults-torrc "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc-defaults" -f "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc" | more
```

Also you need to make sure that the *Working Directory* of CMD is set to be `C:\Tor Browser\Browser\` because the paths referred within `torrc-defaults` file defines paths relatively as you are in the mother folder `TorBrowser` folder.

This is the command line sequence that should make it work successfuly:

```
cd "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\"
"C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe" -f "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc" | more
```

Note: you don't need to include `--defaults-torrc` as you are in the correct working directory the configuration file considers.